# Weirdness on my phone (messages)

Tags: iphone, messages

[image]I've searched a lot about this but couldn't find anything.

I am an iPhone user and while navigating my messages (imessage), I noticed a message box at the bottom named “Anonymous”, dated 19.01.1970, which seems to typing, but nothing and I could not send a message. It didn't have any number or any other information. Could this be spyware or something else harmful? Maybe am i hacked? (Zero click or zero day attack etc.) (Btw, Anonim mean Anonymous in my language)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  A screen shot will be helpful here.

Comment: I think it's more likely something that got lost in transit. Try rebooting the phone.

Comment: It's likely a spam text message.  Just delete it.